# Fire off an event when async javascript is loaded

Tags: javascript, events, asynchronous, onload

I'm changing my external javascript resources to be loaded asynchronously to speed up page load. To do this, I'm adding the **async** property to my script tags:

```
<script async type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>
```

Right before the end of the body tag I have included this code to perform callbacks:

```
if (typeof(myFuncion) === "function") {
    myFunction();
} else {
    window.onload = myFunction;
}
```

Basically, if the external.js was cached, when the parser reach this code the myFunction is defined and it will be executed. If not, then it will have to wait for **all** external resources to be available before calling myFunction. So, myFunction will be waiting for AdSense, Analytics, ... when it really only depends on external.js.

This doesn't make much sense to me. Any suggestions on how to replace the window.onload for something that would fire when external.js is loaded?

Comment: Maybe you can execute function inside `external.js`, so it will be called whenever the file is loaded.

Comment: Yea, at least if I can edit all external javascript. It wouldn't work with any 3rd party javascript. Also, what happens if external.js was cached and it would load _before_ the page was loaded. Hmm..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should inject a script by JavaScript instead of using a `script` tag *so you have a full control over the load event*. See this example below:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'external.js';
script.async = true;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (script.readyState ||
        script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete"){
        // Script loaded!

        // So all dependencies are ready, call the desired function now
        myFunction();
    }
}
```

With this approach, you can capture the event when the script is successfully loaded and trigger an appropriate function afterwards.

Comment: Interesting. Why is there a need for `if ( !done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState === "loaded" || this.readyState === "complete") )` and what happens if this condition isn't fulfilled, myFunction will never be called? For now it's not working for me, could it be cross domain related?

Comment: Actually, you're defining the script object, but you're never injecting it are you?

Comment: I have just modified the script so it injects the script tag. Sorry I missed that in the first place. To make sure the script is correctly loaded, not timeout or anything, you need to check whether the `readystate` has be changed to `loaded` or `complete`.

Comment: Almost there, external.js is loaded correctly, `this.readyState` however is undefined upon `script.onreadystatechange`.

Comment: @jonr Sorry, it should be `script`, not `this`. I have just updated the code. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: Doing some Google for readyState and asynchronous  js loading, I find that people ask for !readyState instead of readyState. Of course this works since it's undefined, it just doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: This is my accepted answer, however instead of asking for `readyState` I ask for `typeof(myFuncion) === "function"` since readyState is undefined at this point.

Comment: I am not sure, you are not mixing two things. I am using this as two cases, = onreadystatechange and then checking readyState is needed for IE. But when the more usual onload is fired, it should only be "loaded" and checking again readyState might not be safe, as the browser might not update this property.

Comment: This makes no sense – the second two equality checks will never be evaluated under any circumstances: `if (script.readyState || script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete")`